# cd to root - not working within Matlab script

Tags: linux, matlab, root, remote-access, cd

I have written a Matlab script that is in my user directory on a remote computer. Within this script it is supposed to change into a data directory that is off of the root directory. Within my script the Matlab code snippet is:

```
data_dir='/data/gcm/';
old_dir=cd(data_dir);
% there's other code in here, then...
cd(old_dir);
```

Within the directory that contains my Matlab script (called launch_WA) I am calling the script using:

```
$ matlab -nodesktop -r "launch_WA;quit"
```

This works on my local machine, and it works on the remote if I copy the data files into a directory under my own user directory, but it won't cd up to anything off of root?

I checked the access restrictions on the data directory with stat:

```
drwxrwxr--
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I believe that to `cd` inmatlab, you need full paths. So you would need to `cd(strct('C:\potato',data_dir))` or `cd(strct('pwd,data_dir))` if it is a subfolder of the current path.

Answer (score 0):

Is it is said in the `cd` [documentation](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cd.html) you need full path to access with cd. you could use relative paths, using `..\` format before the folder name, if you know that it is a level up from your current folder. If you use just `/data/gcm/` Matlab will only look to the current folder.

So, If the folder is inside your current folder

```
cd(data_dir);
```

If you know exactly where it is

```
cd(strcat('C:\potato',data_dir))
```

If you know that it is (e.g. 2 ) levels up

```
cd(strcat('..\..\',data_dir))
```

Comment: The remote machine is running Linux, so the full path to the data directory is `/data/gcm/` since it is off of the root directory. I tried to use your suggestion indicating the number of levels up:  `data_dir='../../../data/gcm` but Matlab is still giving me the same error; that the name is non existent or isn't a directory. @Ander

Comment: @Alison aaaah linux. There is a small example in the cd documentation that suggest you use `~\dir`. You may want to tray it, but I cant help anymore if it is a linux problem.

Comment: Yup linux. On my local (mac) I can use  `/some_dir/off_root` in this code to go up the directory tree from pwd, which is why I think it's odd the same code (just subbing in the new directory on the remote) doesn't work. Using `~/dir` will only take me to my usr home directory not root. Thanks for the ideas anyway! @Ander